# Transmitting structures among controllers

Tags: c, serialization, data-structures, struct, embedded

I want to send a structure having many structures in it to another controller(not the same make of the controller,having a different Architecture).
Im required to develop a sort of serialisation to send data across without using invented serialisation methods available.
How do i find out where padded bytes are added so that I can remove them out before sending it to the other controller?
How can i implement a metadata so that the other controller can reconstruct every member of the structure from the transmitted bytes of data?
Any other points that may be required also would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Fully portable serialization/de-serialization is quite manual. You just go through ever member of the struct and copy it. You could use `offsetof` to spot padding, but that's mostly meaningless practice, since it means you would need to do some "manual coding" per struct member anyway.

`#pragma pack(1)` and similar isn't ideal. Structs are packed for a reason, and there are no portable means to disable padding. It may be feasible on some smaller CPUs like 8 or 16 bit, but not for fully portable code.

What's important is to have a well-defined network protocol, that states how data is stored, *including endianess*.  That is, the sender, the protocol and the receiver all have endianess and they are not necessarily the same.

(Traditionally, data protocols often used big endian since that is the only thing that makes sense for implementing hardware CRC checks with XOR gates, but that's mostly a non-issue nowadays. Some MCUs even have CRC check hardware built-in.)

Comment: Depending on requirements, the "well-defined network protocol" could even be ASCII-based. Such a transfer is way safer and easier to implement and monitor/debug than any binary protocol.

Comment: @tofro Not really, ASCII protocols mean data bloat and slower encoding/decoding. The only reason you would use them is if monitoring should be done by non-programmers. I would avoid implementing old crap like "AT commands".

Comment: Most, if  not all of the thing called Internet is based on such "old crap". Can't be that bad?

Comment: @tofro No, most of the internet is based on TCP/IP.

Comment: You either haven't had a look into TCP/IP packet payload (not likely) or actively ignore what you've seen.

Comment: @tofro Protocols and payloads are different things. If you send crap over the protocol, that's no fault of the protocol itself.

Comment: I individually copy every member and send it across. How do I reconstruct it back?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD The other way around. Copy bytes into struct members.

Comment: @Lundin This question is about serialized data - that is *payload*, not *protocol*

Comment: @tofro You are the one who brought up "ASCII protocols", not me. An ASCII _protocol_ would typically be something old, crappy and UART-based like AT commands.

Comment: @Lundin Or something old and crappy like HTML5?

Comment: @tofro HTML is a markup language, not a network protocol.

Comment: Reconstruction at the other end guys?